# Extraer enteros de una cadena JAVA

Tags: java, array, string, archivo, split

tengo esta cadena (`LIXA ABIMERHI JUAN JOSE,DISEÑO DE INTERFACES,90,88,81,90`)
y me estan pidiendo:

1. Leer los datos por líneas usando el método `split` de la clase `String` separar los campos.
2. Convertir a número entero las 4 cadenas de texto de calificaciones y calcular el promedio de ellas.

(son cadenas contenidas en un archivo)

**Mi código:**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
File file = new File("E:/SEMESTRE2/POO/PROGRAMAS/TareasSem2/src/U6/Calificaciones.txt");
if (!file.exists()) 
{
    System.out.println ("No existe el archivo: "+file);
    System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println ("Archivo Encontrado");
System.out.print ("Escribe El Promedio Minimo ");
int prom = sc.nextInt();
try 
{

    FileReader fr = new FileReader(file);
    BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(fr);
    String linea=bfr.readLine();
    String[] parts = linea.split(","); 

    //nombre> parts[0] materia parts[1] num1 parts [2]

    //System.out.println(linea);
    while (linea != null) 
    {
            double num = 0, mat, promA = 0;
            for(int i = 2;i>=2&&i<=5;i++)
            {

            mat=Double.parseDouble(parts[i]);
            num = num + mat;
            promA = num / 4;

            }
            System.out.println(linea+"  "+promA);


        linea=bfr.readLine();
    }
    /*while (linea != null) 
    {
        double num = 0, mat, promA = 0;
            for(int i = 2;i>=2&&i<=5;i++)
            {

            mat=Double.parseDouble(parts[i]);
            num = num + mat;
            promA = num / 4;

            }

            System.out.println(promA);
        linea=bfr.readLine();
    }*/
    bfr.close();
    fr.close();
}
catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException ex) 
{
    System.out.println ("No existe el archivo: "+file);
}
catch (java.io.IOException ex) 
{
    System.out.println ("Error al leer el archivo: "+file);
}//fin del catch IO
```

ok ya encontre como solo que ahora me imprime siempre el mismo promedio y no reinicia

Comment: perdon es en java

Comment: Hola @JohannDuran te invito a realizar el [tour] para que entiendas el funcionamiento básico del sitio, además así obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Adicionalmente puedes leer [ask]

Comment: Hola Johann. Gracias por hacer el recorrido, y agregar la información que te pedimos. ¿Puedes ahora ser más especifico en cuanto a cual es el problema con el código que ya tienes? ¿Cual es la ayuda **específica** que necesitas?

Comment: @JohannDuran una pregunta si te hace la separación  con el  split ??

Comment: jajaja perdon si doy muchos problemas pero ando en segundo semestre y es tema nuevo lo del flujo de archivos, lo que no se es como en una linea LIXA ABIMERHI JUAN JOSE,DISEÑO DE INTERFACES,90,88,81,90 separar los numeros para que solo me tome (90,88,81,90) obviamente convertirlos a int para poder hacer la suma y sacar el promedio en el ejercicio nos pide utilizar split

Comment: @JohannDuran podria colocar lo que te esta saliendo de salida al momento de ejecutar el código

Comment: [Ljava.lang.String;@4554617c

Comment: @JohannDuran [Edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/119947/edit) y añadelo indicando que es la salida actual.

Comment: El código puesto en la pregunta no compila: el bucle `while (linea.contains()) { }` está incompleto

Comment: yo utilizaria un función y enviaria de paramentro part   public double  promedio(String cadena){
 
    
 int aux = 0;
    for (int i = 0 <cadena.length;i++){
       
 try{
   promedio = Integer.parseInt(cadena[i]);
   aux ++;
 }catch{
  promedio = promedio + 0;
 }
  }   
  promedio = promedio / aux;
 
 
    return promedio;
}

Answer (score 1):

para cargar el archivo se sugiero este código:

```
public List<String> cargarArchivo(String direccion){
    List<String> lineas = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        Path ruta = Paths.get(direccion);
        Stream<String> flujoFormateado = Files.lines(ruta, Charset.forName("UTF-8")); // cargando el archivo plano
        flujoFormateado.forEach(lineas::add); // almacenando todos los elementos para su analisis

        System.out.println("lineas guardadas: "+lineas.size());
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Otros.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return lineas;
}
```

luego de tener todas las lineas de interes puedes recorrerlas y sacar el promedio de cada una de ellas, pero tomando en cuenta el ejemplo que distes puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
public void calculoPromedio(){
    String cadena = "LIXA ABIMERHI JUAN JOSE,DISEÑO DE INTERFACES,90,88,81,90";
    String partes[] = cadena.split(",");

    System.out.println("s: "+cadena.split(",").length);

    double promedio = ( Integer.valueOf(partes[2]) + Integer.valueOf(partes[3]) + Integer.valueOf(partes[4]) + Integer.valueOf(partes[5]) )/4; 
    System.out.println("promedio: "+promedio);        

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Perdoname, ingles es mi primer idioma. No dudes en pedir aclaraciónes.

Podemos hacer la leyendas de cadena con el utilidad `Scanner`.

```
String direccion = "cadenas.dat";
File documento = new File(direccion);
Scanner lector = null;
try {
    lector = new Scanner(documento);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
    System.err.println("No puedo leer " + direccion);
    System.exit(1);
}
System.out.println("Archivo encontrado.");

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Escribe el promedio minimo: ");
double minPromedio = teclado.nextDouble();


// Verificas que el documento tiene mas lineas por leer.
while(lector.hasNextLine()) {
    String linea = lector.nextLine();

    String[] partes = linea.split(",");
    String nombre = partes[0];
    String profesion = partes[1];

    double calSuma = 0; // La suma de los calificaciones
    int cuantosCal = 0; // La numero de calificaciones que inclue en los calculaciones.
    for(int i = 2; i < partes.length; i++) {
        try {
            double calificacion = Double.parseDouble(partes[i]);
            cuantosCal++;
            calSuma += calificacion;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.print("Encontre un numero que no puedo leer.");
            continue; // Omites la numero corriente.
        }
    }

    double promedio = calSuma / cuantosCal;

    System.out.println(nombre + " tiene un calificacion promedio de " + promedio + ".");

    // Verificas que la promedio es el mismo o mas alto de la promedio minimo.
    if(promedio >= minPromedio) {
        System.out.println(nombre
                + " tiene un calification promedio que cumple con el requisito.");
    }
}

lector.close();
teclado.close();
```

Creo que esta código puede hacer que tu quieres, pero esta diseño es difícil para cambio por código que puede reiniciar.

Si te quieres código que puede reiniciar, necesitas poner los lineas en un `List` antes de haces los cálculos, porque la utilidad `Scanner` no puede volver al principio del archivo (excepto cuando reinicializar la `Scanner` objeto).

Answer (score 0):

tengo otro método mediante el cual puedes sacar los tres números sin problemas en un *array* y después manipular dichas notas como *int* para realizar lo que tu quieras con ello.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    File file = new File("/home/pietrodeocre/git/EjerciciosDAMeclipse/src/PracticasStackOverFlow/Texto.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println ("No existe el archivo: "+file);
        System.exit(1);
    }
    System.out.println ("Archivo Encontrado");
    //System.out.print ("Escribe El Promedio Minimo ");
    //int prom = sc.nextInt();
    int[] notas = new int[4];
    List<String> infoList = new ArrayList<String>();
    infoList = tokenizador(file);

    for(int i = 0; i< infoList.size();i++) {
        notas[0]  = new Integer(infoList.get(i+2));
    }

    notas[1]  = new Integer(infoList.get(3));
    notas[2]  = new Integer(infoList.get(4));
    notas[3]  = new Integer(infoList.get(5));

    System.out.println("Nostas: " +notas[0] + ", " + notas[1]+ ", " + notas[2] + ", " + notas[3] );

}

/*
 * Devuelve una lista con las palabras de un archivo
 */
public static List<String> tokenizador(File ruta) {

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedReader dais = null;
    String cadenaString = null;
    StringTokenizer tokenizador = null;
    String tok = null;
    List<String> tokList = null;

    try {

        fis = new FileInputStream(ruta);
        dais = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
        tokList = new ArrayList<String>();

        while ((cadenaString = dais.readLine()) != null) {

            tokenizador = new StringTokenizer(cadenaString, ",");

            while (tokenizador.hasMoreTokens()) {

                tok = tokenizador.nextToken();

                tokList.add(tok);

            }

        }       

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            dais.close();
        } catch (final IOException e2) {
            e2.printStackTrace();
        }finally {

        }
    }
    return tokList;
}
```

Espero que te sirva y a los demás para hacer uso de la clase *StringTokenizer* que es muy útil.